# Is it possible to do a pre-release a formula for homebrew?

Tags: installation, package, homebrew, formula

I want to pre-release a formula to homebrew so that even the new version is released as part of pre-release when user installs `brew install package` we should get the non pre-release package.
For example I have a package `test-pre-release` and versions are

```
x.y.z+1-rc -> latest pre-release 
x.y.z -> previous
```

and when user wants to install `brew install test-pre-release` it should get the non pre-release versio i.e., x.y.z. Is it possible to do that in brew?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what I answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874131/791609), you can create duplicate your current `formula.rb` as `formula-rc.rb` and Then rename `class Formula` into `class FormulaRc`, and commit the changes to do the pre-release testing.