# How do you mark a homebrew package as a release candidate?

Tags: homebrew, release-candidate

Say a homebrew package was released for internal testing purposes. Basically a release candidate. How do I mark the homebrew package as a release candidate so that it doesn't get installed when a user tries to install the latest package? I need the latest stable package to get installed.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I think of is to create a separate pre-release `tap` or `formula`, so that you can install that `tap` or `formula` to do the pre-release testing.

Let's say if you sue formula approach, you can have `formula.rb` and `formula-rc.rb` in the same tap. And you can `brew install/test formula-rc` to achieve your goal.